# Some backlogs are not display on menu 'Backlog' at TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, display, invisible, backlog

I'm using TFS 2015, with Scrum process template.

I noticed that some backlogs are not displayed using menu 'Backlog' or 'Board' and are just displayed on query or search. 
I'm sure that it is not related with a specific iteration. I got experiences this issues sometimes.
It makes me missing some backlogs when I organize the backlogs.

Can I get an information to solve this situation?
I'm sure that query is no problem, however some managers want to use without doing something.

For example:
normally, The backlogs are displayed as follows.

backlog: #1234 (child:#5678
   bug : #5678 (parent:#1234)

However, In this case, #5678 is just displayed and #1234 isn't.
so, I have to query to see #1234 or search on #1234 If I want to see.

I hope there are displayed all backlogs on TFS normally.

Comment: What do you mean by "backlog"? Are you talking about Product Backlog Items?

Comment: I suspect that there are some nested workitems in your backlog, can you check it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/resolve-backlog-reorder-issues?view=vsts#how-backlogs-and-boards-display-hierarchical-nested-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have enabled the [`Show Parents` and expand the tree hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/organize-backlog?view=vsts#show-parents-and-expand-the-tree-hierarchy) on the Backlog.

[image]

---

UPDATE:

You need to clarify your question. What's that mean for "`backlog`" you mentioned here? a `PBI` or just a `bug`?

If you can not see the Parents wits, then you need to enable `Parents: Show`.

If you mean the `Bugs` can not  be displayed  on the Backlog, then you can set the `Working with bugs` in SETTINGS just as you mentioned.

If you mean you cannot see other `Backlog navigation levels`, then just select the specific  `Backlog navigation level` in SETTINGS- > General -> Backlogs -> Backlog navigation levels

Comment: Thank you for your information. However there are many items in my case.
and I couldn't see a backlog that invisible now.

I noticed at this time. 
the backlog are displayed via backlog's settings, working with bugs.

1, Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with requirements.: X (I can't)
2. Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks.: O (I can see)
3. Bugs do not appear on backlogs or boards.: O 

I hope I would understand what happens there...
Please, let me know the root cause...

Comment: @배금동 Not sure what are you talking about, you need to clarify your question. What's that mean for "`backlog`" you mentioned here? a `PBI` or just a `bug`? If you can not see the Parents wits, then you need to enable `Parents: Show`. If you mean the `Bugs` can not  be displayed  on the Backlog, then you can set the `Working with bugs` in SETTINGS just as you mentioned. If you mean you cannot see other `Backlog navigation levels`, then just select the specific  `Backlog navigation level` in SETTINGS- > General -> Backlogs

Comment: Thank  you for your great information. "backlog" means PBI. my original question is some backlogs(PBI) are not displayed on 1 of settings "Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with requirements". I hope my question is clear why some PBI are invisible on the settings.

Comment: @배금동 I still cannot reproduce your issue. Everything works in Backlog tab on my side. Do you mean that some PBIs are not displayed on **Board** with the settings "`Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with requirements`"? If it is,  then please note that, based on my test the previous PBIs will not be displayed there, only new PBIs which created **after changing the settings** will display there.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is solved that I just added a task to the PBI. and I can see the PBI with a bug as child relationship together. that's all. ;) I could handle it now even though a root of cause is not clear.